# Function re.findall returns list with strings, contain only one symbol

Tags: python, python-re, findall

```
import re

s = 'ddvvrwwwrggg'
print(re.findall(r'(.)\1*', s))  # -> ['d', 'v', 'r', 'w', 'r', 'g'] 

a = list()
for i in re.finditer(r'(.)\1*', s):
    a.append(i.group())

print(a)  # -> ['dd', 'vv', 'r', 'www', 'r', 'ggg']
```

Why do findall and finditer give different results? I need finditer's one, the output should be `['dd', 'vv', 'r', 'www', 'r', 'ggg']`, but I don't want to use cycles. Or is there a better way to get all sub-strings with all the same symbols in it?

Comment: You want `.group(1)`, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group. Another way to do it is `[key for key, group in itertools.groupby(s)]` - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby.

Comment: no, I want result ['dd', 'vv', 'r', 'www', 'r', 'ggg'] using findall

Comment: Oh, I see. What do you mean by *"I don't want to use cycles"*, why *not* use `finditer`?

Comment: I mean, I need one-string solution without using "for" or other loops. This is just experiment for me to understand how it works.

Comment: You mean one-*line* solution? Why? Can you use a *list comprehension*, like I put in my first comment, or are you trying to avoid the word `for` entirely (again, why)?

Comment: I have special task to make one-line solution. And I don't know, if I can use just findall, or I need to get elements from finditer using "for"

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed surprising but according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall). In contrast to `re.finditer`, `re.findall` behaves as follows in case of one or more groups are present in the pattern:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
> groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
> group.

So, the behavior difference is indeed surprising but "as designed".

The expression you're probably looking for is:

```
[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'(.)\1*', s)]
```

Comment: This expression returns match's list. So, I only can use map(), lambda and grop() to convet it into normal form?

Comment: I think like this:    list(map(lambda x: x.group(), re.finditer(r'(.)\1*', s)))

Comment: @FlintCQ I changed the expression in my answer.